# Module is free of finite rank $\implies$ submodule is free of finite rank?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $M$ be $R$-module, where $R$ is commutative ring with $1,$ and $N$ be submodule of $M.$
If $M$ is free of finite rank, so is $N \ ?$

Answer: False. Let $R=M=\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $N=2\mathbb{Z}_6.$ Clearly, $M$ is free of finite rank. Since $|N|\neq |M^k|, $ we have $\ N \not\cong M^k, \  \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0},$

May I know if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Comment: Looks good. You might mention the actual numbers in your proof as well, but it is very clear.

Comment: Your proof seems fine.  Here's another simple example.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (which is not a PID) with $1$, and let $I$ be an $R$-ideal which is not principal.  Then $R$ is a free $R$-module, and $I$ is a submodule of the free module $R$, which is not free.  For a concrete application of this, consider $R = \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, $I = (X,Y)$.